# Good free chart library for Android

Tags: android

I need some decent chart library for my app. It must be free to non or commercial use. I've tried  Androidplot. It was easy to use but charts were kinda ugly, and project is pretty much dead as I've noticed. Also there are no pie charts which I also need.

Comment: Androidplot is definitely not dead, and pie charts have been added.  As far as ugliness, plot styling is left to the developer to alter to suit the app's theme.  The stock theme could be improved but it's certainly not due to a lack of support for styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read about AChartEngine. It is used in calculator++ application. Source codes are here: 
[source](https://github.com/serso/android_calculator)

Comment: yeah this is probably the right choice, was checking that out too yesterday. However, maybe there is still something more out there :)